# BackgroundWorker not starting again when once finished

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, windows-10

I have a WinForms application which uses a backgroundworker for downloading images from given urls. For the download I use a backgroundworker.
The application is running fine when started, and the download happens as planned, but when the worker is done and I click the downloadbutton again to start downloading from another url, the backgroundworker doesn't do anything.

I fixed that problem temporarily by calling application.restart() when the worker is done, which works but can't be here longer than it has to.

Worker-Code:

```
// initialization of worker is done in constructor of my class
downloadWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
downloadWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

downloadWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_doWork);
downloadWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_progressChanged);
downloadWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_runWorkerCompleted);
// ...
private void worker_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient();   
    HttpWebRequest HttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)HttpReq.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    }

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    MessageBox.Show("Website not found");
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        {
            string image = getImageUrl(url,i);
            downloadWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            image = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(image);
            string saveName = "img_"+i+".png";
            try
            {
                downloadClient.DownloadFile(image, saveName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }
    }
}
private void worker_progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    rtxtStatus.AppendText("Downloade Image" + e.ProgressPercentage + " of 3");
}
private void worker_runWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Download completed");
}
```

edit:

```
if (e.Error != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
}
```

To avoid any misunderstandings: The backgroundWorker is definetely running at the second time, and it is not an error of the reportProgress-method, since I get the same thing when I dont report anything.

edit no. 2:

I found out where the error came from: at the second run, the for-loop is completely skipped. But that doesn't make any sense for me either... There can't be any other value still be in because I have a completely new instance of the class, can it? But anyway, if it just skipped the method the worker still should exit which it doesn't do. For testing, I added a MessageBox after the for-loop, which is not executed after the second run.

Comment: Do you get an error? Probably one that says you cant access rtctStatus from another thread or so

Comment: Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler is borken, checking the `e.Error` property is never optional.  It tells you what exception made the DoWork event handler keel over.  You have to do something about it, at least let the user know.  Or just quit the program because there isn't any real way to recover from such a mishap.  Debug it by forcing the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.  Debug > Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: Does it work when you comment out `// rtxtStatus.AppendText("Downloade Image" + e.ProgressPercentage + " of 3");`

Comment: Why do you use Html-Agility-Pack just for downloading images? HAP is used to _parse_ DOM using Xpath. I'm sure that there are plenty of better ways to download a simple image...

Comment: UI Controls should be accessed through Dispatcher thread. BackgroundWorker is not a dispatcher, so I believe you will need to use dispatcher object to append text to the status bar or display message box.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I'll check that @HansPassant. I think it is standard to use reportProgress-method of a backgroundWorker for telling the user about the current status? DoWork not, but ReportProgress, usually via progressBar? When running it at first it works perfectly also.

Comment: Please re-read my comment, it did not talk about ReportProgress.

Comment: @HansPassant I added the code I edited in my question, but it's not called, also I don't get any exceptions...

Comment: You don't have any of the code for where you create and start the worker or set the URL. For all we know you're hooking up events multiple times too.

Comment: @kjbartel I have this site https://unsplash.com/ as url, the getImag-method gets the first x image (in my for loop: first, second, third) image from the site. the urls are alright, like https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453974336165-b5c58464f1ed?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=a408029a8360a3efbdd1c9779141e864

Comment: The event itself is starting when a button is pressed, I press it again when the first worker is done.

Comment: Only add the event handlers once.

Comment: @LarsTech that seems to make sense! But I have the problem that the worker itself uses a lot of the objects & variables of the class it is in. Also, I generate a new instance of this class everytime I click the button. My new approach will be to create a standalone class for the BackgroundWorker, which I will try later. Or is there a shorter method without heaving to put all that stuff in another class? By that I mean for example to check if the handlers are already been added.